# Custom TinyMCE style formats disabled

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, dropdown

I've created a `TinyMCE` style `dropdown` for the `TinyMCE` WordPress editor.

The formats are appearing as expected on the editor but when the drop down is expanded to choose from a style, they are showing as disabled - would there by any reason for this?  My code is attached below.

[image: Drop down options showing grey & disabled]

```
function new_mce_button($buttons) {

    array_unshift($buttons, 'styleselect');
    return $buttons;

}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'new_mce_button');

/**
 * Callback function to filter the MCE settings
 */
function custom_formats( $init_array ) {  

    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'White Button',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'cta wht',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Grey Button',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'cta gry'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Light Blue Button',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'cta lblue'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Dark Blue Button',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'cta dblue'
        ),
    );  

    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

    return $init_array;  

} 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'custom_formats' );
```

Comment: In your function you've set the selector to work only in anchor (a) tags.

Comment: Thanks, @Karun - worked a treat when I updated from `'selector' => 'a'` to `'block' => 'div'`.  Can't believe I couldn't see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @karun, the text first needed to be made into a hyperlink, after which the formats became active.

Changing the array values to

```
array(
  'title' => 'Grey Button',
  'block' => 'div',
  'classes' => 'cta gry'
),
```

made the style permanently available.